# Intel core I5 2500k: quad core?

Tags: cpu, cpu-cores

I have an Intel Core I5 2500K. I saw on [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Core_i5_microprocessors) that my processor has 4 cores. So is it a quad core? I don't understand, maybe it is 4 threads?

Comment: https://ark.intel.com/products/52210/Intel-Core-i5-2500K-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_70-GHz

Comment: Not all processors have hyperthreading. In the last few years the general trend has been for i3's and i7's to have hyperthreading and i5 to be "simply" cores. so i3 = 2C/4T, i5 = 4C/4T, and i7 = 4C/8T.

Answer (score 2):

> So is it a quad core?  I don't understand, maybe it is 4 threads...

Yes; Your processor would be considered a quad-core processor.  Yes;  It does indeed support only 4 threads.

> [image]

[Intel® Core™ i5-2500K Processor](https://ark.intel.com/products/52210/Intel-Core-i5-2500K-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_70-GHz)

Comment: I am not going to explain the difference between cores and threads, mainly because, the question didn't ask to clarify the difference.

Answer (score 0):

TlDR; Yes, 4 core is four cores.

Longer version:

1. Tread != core.
2. Core: Full core. Doing real work. Double the cores up to twice the calculating power (usually adding one core means about 180%, or 80% gain due to extra overhead, IO bound stuff etc)
3. Tread usually is mentioned when Intel hypertreading or any similar is used. Part of a real core is duplicated. In perfect conditions twice as much work can be done. I worst case conditions things even slow down. Realistic world average: 8 treads on a 4 core CPU is roughly 1/3rd faster and a plain 4 core CPU.